# Popular uma ListView com ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

Preciso popular uma `ListView`. Tenho uma classe que representa a Entidade `Cliete`,
um classe que é responsável pelas persistências do Banco de Dados e por fim uma classe `ClienteDAO`, que persiste os dados da entidade `Cliente`.

Seguem as Classes:

**ClienteDAO**

```
public class ClienteDAO {

private SQLiteDatabase DB;
    protected Banco auxBanco;
    private String TABELA = "CLIENTE";

    public ClienteDAO(Context context)
    {
            Banco newBanco = new Banco(context);
    DB = newBanco.getWritableDatabase();
    //newBanco.onCreate(DB);
    this.auxBanco = newBanco;
}

public ArrayList<Cliente> Listar_Clientes(){

    ArrayList<Cliente> list = new ArrayList<Cliente>();

    String[] colunas = new String[]{"_ID", 
                                    "NOME",
                                    "APELIDO",
                                    "OBSERVACAO",
                                    "CELULAR",
                                    "DATA_CADASTRO",
                                    "DDD"};

    Cursor Sn = DB.query(this.TABELA, colunas, null, null, null, null, "NOME ASC");

    if(Sn.getCount() > 0){
        Sn.moveToFirst();

        do{ 
            Cliente newCliente = new Cliente();
            newCliente.set_ID(Sn.getLong(Sn.getColumnIndex("_ID")));
            newCliente.setNome(Sn.getString(Sn.getColumnIndex("NOME")));
            newCliente.setApelido(Sn.getString(Sn.getColumnIndex("APELIDO")));
            newCliente.setCelular(Sn.getString(Sn.getColumnIndex("CELULAR")));
            newCliente.setDDD(Sn.getString(Sn.getColumnIndex("DDD")));
            newCliente.setObservacao(Sn.getString(Sn.getColumnIndex("OBSERVACAO")));
            newCliente.setCelular(Sn.getString(Sn.getColumnIndex("DATA_CADASTRO")));
            list.add(newCliente);

        }while(Sn.moveToNext());
    }
    return(list);
    }
```

**ClienteAdapter**

```
public class ClienteAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Cliente> list;

    public ClienteAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Cliente> list){
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        list.size();
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        list.get(position);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Cliente cCliente = list.get(position);
        View layout;

        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            layout  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itens_relacao_cliente, null);
        }else
        {
            layout = convertView;
        }

        TextView Nome = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.lblNome);
        Nome.setText(cCliente.getNome());

        TextView Apelido = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.lblApelido);
        Apelido.setText(cCliente.getApelido());

        return layout;
        }
    }
```

**Relacao_Clientes**

```
public class Relacao_cliente extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_relacao_cliente);

    try {
        ClienteDAO BD = new ClienteDAO(this);
        ArrayList<Cliente> Lista_Clientes =  BD.Listar_Clientes();

        ListView ListViewR_Cliente = (ListView)     findViewById(R.id.lvRelacao_Cliente);
        ListViewR_Cliente.setAdapter(new ClienteAdapter(this,  Lista_Clientes));

            } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual é sua dúvida? A princípio o código faz o que deveria, de acordo com sua pergunta.

Comment: O código não faz o que deveria. Gostaria de saber se algo está sendo feito errado, se algum objeto precisa ter um tratamento específico antes de ser passado para outra classe.
Nesta chamada eu percebi(debugando) que ele não entra no `public View getView`(ClienteAdapter).
`ListViewR_Cliente.setAdapter(new ClienteAdapter(this,  Lista_Clientes));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agora entendi o problema com seu código, na verdade tem um pequeno erro no `Adapter`, esqueceu de retornar os dados de verdade.

A classe com os acertos é:

```
public class ClienteAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Cliente> list;

    public ClienteAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Cliente> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
        // Em vez de return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
        // Em vez de return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Restante do codigo ok
    }
}
```

Como retornou 0 no `getCount`, o `ListView` acha que o `Adapter` esta vazio, logo nada é gerado. Acredito que com esses acertos seu `Adapter` funcione.

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo aqui...